# Lazy loading collection data through granular subscriptions and OOP (Meteor.js)

Tags: object-oriented, prototyping, pubsub

I am transforming my Meteor collection to a class I've created:

```
People = new Mongo.Collection('people', {
  transform: function(doc) {
    return new Person(doc);
  }
});
```

Person has a bunch of methods, some of which control getting the data:

```
var john = People.findOne({ name: 'John' });
john.getFullName();
```

I also have some data that is not needed as often:

```
john.getAddress();
```

To avoid subscribing to data that's not needed, I have the `people` subscription only return summary data:

```
Meteor.publish('people', function() {
  return People.find({}, { fields: { firstName: 1, lastName: 1, email: 1 } });
});
```

While address data is subscribed to through the publication `people_addresses`.

My question regarding granular subscriptions in this format is: Where should the subscription be handled?

## Option 1: Callbacks

Set up the `getAddress` method to subscribe to the data if we don't already have it:

```
People.prototype.getAddress = function(callback, fail) {
  var that = this;

  if (this._address) {
    callback(this._address);
  } else {
    Meteor.subscribe('people_addresses', this.getName(), function() {
      /*
       * Need to either update the current object to reflect the data
       * or make the class reactive somehow... any ideas?
       */ 

      callback(that._address);
    });
  }
};
```

Use the method with a callback to access the data:

```
john.getAddress(function(address) {
  /* Use Johns address data. */ 
});
```

## Option 2: Data Preparation

Here we would be in a place where we know we're going to need address data.

```
Meteor.subscribe('people_addresses', 'john' function() {
  var john = People.findOne({ name: 'john' }), 
    address;

  address = john.getAddress();

  /* Use John's address */
});
```

**Option #1** hides the complexity, but would need an elegant solution for updating the object with the newly received `address` data.

It also requires callbacks (or promises if we go that route) where **Option #2** only requires wrapping the code in the subscribe.

What are your thoughts on handling granular data subscriptions? Are either of these options viable?